# Set proof using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, induction

suppose I'm given a set $X_i = \{1,2,...i\}$. How do I use induction to prove that $\bigcap_{i \in N} X_i$ = {1}, where N is the set of natural numbers. Here is my approach: For the base case, $i=1$ satisfies $X_1$ = $\bigcap_{i \in 1} X_i$ = {1}. For inductive steps, I assumed $j$ to be in $N$ such that $\bigcap _{i \in \{1,2,...j\}} X_i = {1}$. Now it is easy to show that the intersection of this set with $X_{j+1}$ is also equal to $\{1\}$ and thus the proof is complete by induction. Is my logic good? (I need to write it more formally but thats my idea)

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: If $N$ means the set of all natural numbers, then your proof isn't complete. You've shown that, for each natural number $j$, the intersection $\bigcap_{i\leq j}X_i$ is $\{1\}$, but each of those is the intersection of finitely many (in fact exactly $j$) of the $X_i$'s, whereas $\bigcap_{i\in N}X_i$ is the intersection of infinitely many $X_i$'s.   (Also, there are a couple of places where you wrote $1$ but meant $\{1\}$.)

Comment: You can't use induction to prove this, induction only proves statement $P(j)$ for finite $j\in\Bbb N$, not for $j\to\infty$. A property that is true for all finite $n\in \Bbb N$ may not hold for the limiting case.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\bigcap_{1 \le k  \le n + 1} X_k = \left(\bigcap_{1 \le k \le n} X_k\right) \cap X_{n + 1}$.

By induction:

**Base:**

$\begin{align*}
   \bigcap_{1 \le k \le 1} X_k
     &= X_1
      = \{1\}
\end{align*}$

OK.

**Induction:** Assume it is valid for $n$, see $n + 1$:

$\begin{align*}
  \bigcap_{1 \le k \le n + 1} X_k
    &= \left(\bigcap_{1 \le k \le n} X_k\right) \cap X_{n + 1} \\
    &= \{1\} \cap X_{n + 1} \\
    &= \{1\}
\end{align*}$